# Rename a list of file with names from another list

Tags: bash, loops, file-rename

I have a list like the following, in a file called lista.txt:

```
mickey
donald
daffy 
bugs
```

I have a folder containing many files: filename1, filename2, ... filenameN.

I want to iterate through those files to achieve:

```
filename1 => mickey 
filename2 => donald ...
```

Can you provide me working sample code for this task?

Comment: Do you have any criteria for mapping of the files in the folder to strings? I am asking this because: if you use let say `ls` to get the files, you will get sorted alphabetically, but eventually, you can have different mapping `filename_X => string_Y`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not my style to do your work for you. I'd rather you post what you've already tried, so I can help you debug it, but this problem is so easy, I'm going to bite anyway.

```
x=1; for y in $(cat lista.txt); do mv $y filename$x; let x=$x+1; done
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a terrible mistake in my question. The real filenames are not numbered but casual. NOT f1,f2... fn. BUT f_a,f_pippo,f123 and so on... How can I interact with the two lists?

Answer (score 6):

Using bash arrays:

```
files=( * )
i=0
while read -r new_name; do
  mv "${files[$i]}" "$new_name"
  (( i++ ))
done < lista.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let "count=1"

for newname in $(cat lista.txt); do
  mv "filename$count" "$newname"
  let "count++"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I used double redirection with new file descriptors to rename all flac files of a directory according to a given "filelist.txt" this way:

```
while read -u 9 filename ; do  
    read -u 8 newname 
    echo mv "$filename" "$newname" 
done 9<<<"$(ls -1 *flac)" 8< filelist.txt
```

Each .flac file name on the directory goes through file descriptor 9 to the variable "filename" while in the same iteration, each line of the filelist.txt goes through file descriptor 8 to the variable "newname".

Yes, one of the new file descriptors could have been avoided and simply use the default standard input (deleting "-u 9" and "9"), but I got used to not use stdin for those; that way you can include a read statement inside the loop for interactivity or control, and it won't be filled by the redirected data.

The echo is for "test-only" and should be deleted after approving the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use small linux app name krename, with javascript plugin turned on. It is a free tool with very powerful renaming capabilities.

1. Install Krename and open it
2. Add files
3. Go to plugins tab and add your javascript function to function definitions section, something like this:

   ```
   var files = [
       "Mickey",
       "Donald",
       "Duffy"
   ];

   function rename(){
     // krename_index is one of many special variables which can be added via ui
     return files[krename_index];
   }
   ```

This is a simple script that gets the job done, but it can be as complex as you like.

4. Go to filename tab and call your function in the template input as shown below:

   `[js; rename()]`

You can prefix the above code with `$` to keep the original file name and add to it. You can use "Functions" button to experiment further.

5. Preview new names and assign new names by clicking Finish button.

Comment: I'm running krename5 under gnome. I've written a simple js function but clicking the Test... button does nothing. I can save and load the function to and from a file but I see no way to make the function rename2 show up in the functions dialog or plugins' js tab. What might I be doing wrong?